# Passing json_encode to chart.js won't work

Tags: javascript, php, json, chart.js

I'm trying to create a pie chart using chart.js (newest version).

I've made an array, which I'd want to output as the data variable for the chart.

That's the PHP code:

```
<?php if($os != null) {
   $tiposOs = array('Orçamento'=> "#5DC1E3",
                    'Aberto'=> "#07D7F7",
                    'Faturado' => "#07F7CB",
                    'Em Andamento' => "#FFD724",
                    'Finalizado' => "#30C70A",
                    'Cancelado' => "#FF2B2B");
    $chartOsData = array();
    $chartOsData['type'] = 'pie';
    $chartOsData['data'] = array();
    $chartOsData['options'] = array('responsive'=>true);

    foreach ($os as $o)
    {
        $chartOsData['data']['labels'][] = $o->status;
        $chartOsData['data']['datasets']['data'][] = (int)$o->total;
        $chartOsData['data']['datasets']['backgroundColor'][] = $tiposOs[$o->status];
    }
?>
```

This is my script with encoded values:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var osChartc = document.getElementById('osChart').getContext('2d');
        var osChart = new Chart(osChartc, <?php echo json_encode($chartOsData); ?>);
    });
</script>
```

According to the [documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#doughnut-pie-chart), this is how you create a chart:

```
var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: data,
    options: options
});
```

And this is the kind of input for the data variable:

```
var data = {
    labels: [
        "Red",
        "Blue",
        "Yellow"
    ],
    datasets: [
        {
            data: [300, 50, 100],
            backgroundColor: [
                "#FF6384",
                "#36A2EB",
                "#FFCE56"
            ],
            hoverBackgroundColor: [
                "#FF6384",
                "#36A2EB",
                "#FFCE56"
            ]
        }]
};
```

This is what I'm getting:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var osChartc = document.getElementById('osChart').getContext('2d');
    var osChart = new Chart(osChartc,{
        "type": "pie",
        "data": {
            "labels": ["Aberto", "Em Andamento"],
            "datasets": {
                "data": [1, 1],
                "backgroundColor": ["#07D7F7", "#FFD724"]
            }
        },
        "options": {
            "responsive": true
        }
    });
});
```

I believe the array format is correct, except that the keys have quotes around them, and there is no square brackets on the datasets.

The chart is not being built and I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

What can be done?

Comment: **`hoverBackgroundColor` is not obligatory**

Comment: Quotes on the keys are irrelevant. No square brackets on the datasets means that your `datasets` is one object, instead of the array of objects you probably expect. That means you're not constructing your data the way you want/need to. JSON isn't your issue.

Comment: How can I output the datasets as an object?

Comment: You *are* outputting them as one object. If you expect "square brackets" instead, you need to construct an *array instead*. What exactly do you expect for your `datasets`?

Comment: Ah, sorry, one of your blocks shows the expected data...

Comment: Change `$chartOsData['data']['datasets']` to `$chartOsData['data']['datasets'][0]` to make it more like what you say is expected.

Comment: hahaha adding [0] to the datasets made it work. Add it as an answer so I can tick it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$chartOsData['data']['datasets']['data'][] = (int)$o->total;
$chartOsData['data']['datasets']['backgroundColor'][] = $tiposOs[$o->status];
```

Here you're constructing `datasets` as an object with the keys `data` and `backgroundColor`.

```
datasets: [
    {
        data: [300, 50, 100],
        backgroundColor: [...],
    }
]
```

Here you're showing that `datasets` should be an *array* containing one object with those keys.

The fix is simple: make `datasets` an array:

```
$chartOsData['data']['datasets'][0]['data'][] = (int)$o->total;
$chartOsData['data']['datasets'][0]['backgroundColor'][] = $tiposOs[$o->status];
                                ^^^
```